# python group by and count Columns for each line

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file which contains n numbers of row and each row has n number of columns with one delimiter.

```
File :

x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x
x|x|x
x|x|x|x
x|x|x
```

i want to take like below output

```
out:
```

group by Columns (same number of columns ) - count of Columns - line no

```
2 - 4 -  line 1, line 5
1 - 6 - line 2
1 - 11 - line 3
2 - 3 - line 4,line 6
```

can you help?  i tried with pandas but i couldn't succeed.

Comment: Can you put in your question the code you have right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You definitely don't need Pandas; `collections.defaultdict` is your friend.

```
import io
from collections import defaultdict

# Could be a `open(...)` instead, but we're using a
# StringIO to make this a self-contained program.

data = io.StringIO("""
x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x|x
x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x
x|x|x
x|x|x|x
x|x|x
""".strip())

linenos_by_count = defaultdict(set)

for lineno, line in enumerate(data, 1):
    count = line.count("|") + 1  # Count delimiters, add 1
    linenos_by_count[count].add(lineno)

for count, linenos in sorted(linenos_by_count.items()):
    lines_desc = ", ".join(f"line {lineno}" for lineno in sorted(linenos))
    print(f"{len(linenos)} - {count} - {lines_desc}")
```

outputs

```
2 - 3 - line 4, line 6
2 - 4 - line 1, line 5
1 - 6 - line 2
1 - 11 - line 3
```

Comment: thanks for answer. my file 12,4 milion line. i am working with your code but i cant get right output. is big file method different normal read method? or txt file line character is limited? because about 7,8 milion lines have same number coloumns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) based on @AKX approach:

```
from itertools import groupby
print('\n'.join([f'{len(G)} - {k} - '+', '.join([f'line {x[0]+1}' for x in G])
                 for k, g in groupby(sorted(enumerate([s.count('x')
                                                       for s in data.split('\n')
                                                       ]),
                                            key=lambda x: x[1]),
                                     lambda x: x[1]
                                     )
                 for G in [list(g)]
                 ]))
```

output:

```
2 - 3 - line 4, line 6
2 - 4 - line 1, line 5
1 - 6 - line 2
1 - 11 - line 3
```

Below is a less barbaric formatting:

```
from itertools import groupby
counts = [s.count('x') for s in data.split('\n')]
for k, g in groupby(sorted(enumerate(counts),
                           key=lambda x: x[1]),
                    lambda x: x[1]):
    G = list(g)
    print(f'{len(G)} - {k} - '+', '.join([f'line {x[0]+1}' for x in G]))
```

Comment: If the value is not always `x`, then count the `|` and add 1. Replace the occurrences of `s.count('x')` with `s.count('|')+1` and it should work fine.

Comment: sory my friends. I've realized now and then i delete my tag. but you are very fast. thans for help. but i cant get output to txt file.  my file 12,4 milion line. i am working with your code but i cant get right output. is big file method different normal read method? or txt file line character is limited? because about 7,8 milion lines have same number coloumns.